# Building jar from Intelli-J won't execute

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I've been digging through posts about this all evening, and can't seem to find a solution that works for me.  I got my artifact all set up, built my jar, ran 'java -jar myProject.jar' and received this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.myProject.MyProject
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.myProject.MyProject
```

I've extracted the jar file and the class file is there.  I'm still relatively new to Java, so I'm not sure if this is relevant, but within the jar file if I click to edit "MyProject.class", the contents look like this:

```
Êþº¾
```

Other than that, I'm not sure where else to look.  My source directory is set up correctly, the "com" package is in the first layer of the jar file.

Might be worth noting too that this is a Spring-boot application using Maven.

EDIT:

Above I edited the package down to com.myProject.MyProject (for simplicity), but there's another layer in there, which is reflected in the code below, "com.myProject.myProject.MyProject".  Sorry if that's confusing :/

MyProject.java:

```
package com.myProject.myProject;

// imports excluded for brevity

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyProject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyProject.class, args);
}

// Fix the CORS errors
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    // *** URL below needs to match the Vue client URL and port ***
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:8080"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
    bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return bean;
}
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
<artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myProject</name>
<description>My Project</description>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.myProject.myProject.MyProject</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-session-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

</project>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.myProject.myProject.MyProject
Start-Class: com.myProject.myProject.MyProject
```

UPDATE:
I have also tried creating the jar using mvn install, and the resulting jar file throws the same error when attempting to run it.

Comment: What is the structure of the extracted jar?

Comment: The structure of the jar is com.myProject.MyProject with the META-INF at the base level with com as well.

Comment: What is the content of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file inside jar? See e.g. https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/executable-jar-structure.html for example of the content. You see there are e.g. `Main-Class` and `Start-Class` defined.

Comment: I updated to include to contents of MANIFEST.MF - Previously did not have Start-Class included, so I added that and tried again with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot requires you to have the main class specified in the `<start-class>` tag of the properties in your pom.xml

```
<properties>
<!-- The main class to start by executing "java -jar"-->
<start-class>com.myProject.MyProject</start-class>
</properties>
```

**EDIT**

Your package structure according to your pom.xml file should look like the below
[image]

If you are certain that there is only one main entry point to your application. Then try updating your starter pom.xml to the below basic dependencies and perform a `mvn clean install` before executing the generated jar.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.myProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproject</name>
    <description>My Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: I'm using: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/>
 </parent>
and added: <start-class>com.myProject.MyProject</start-class> to my properties, and am still having no luck.  I'm getting the same error

Comment: Can you update with your question with the MyProject.java and pom file? I'd like to see the package structure and annotation used.

Comment: Absolutely, I edited the post to include the main class as well as the pom file.

Comment: I got this working last night - I added:
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
to the pom then did `mvn clean install`,  and it's working now.  Thanks!